# Bash script to take snapshots when movement is detected

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

This script runs on my Raspberry Pi. I want to read the status of a motion sensor which returns 0 or 1. With raspistill I take a photo. It works fine but somehow the part with the `echo "motionb is 0"` is called very often. I wanted it to only be called once and then not anymore when there is no motion.

Also does anybody have some improvement suggestions? I appreciate any kind of help :)

```
#!/bin/bash

motionB=false

while true; do
        motion=$(gpio read 0)
        if [ $motion -eq 1 ]
        then
                if [ "$motionB"==false ]
                then
                        echo "Want to take photo!"
                        DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
                        raspistill -vf -hf -o /var/www/images/$DATE.jpg
                        motionB=true
                        echo "Took Photo!!"
                fi
        else
                if [ "$motionB"==true ]
                then
                        echo "motionB is false"
                        motionB=false
                fi
        fi
done
```

Comment: Errr... `true` and `false`? In bash?

Comment: Sorry I meant 0 and 1 :D

Comment: `true` and `false` are used here as strings; but they also are commands, and you can write `while true` or `if true`.

Comment: Did you also mean to add space around `==`?  eg `if [ "$motionB" = 0 ]` (and use `=` instead of `==`?)

Comment: What does `gpio read 0` do

Comment: @Jidder this is from the wiringpi library and this command returns the state of the connected thingy at wiringpi port 0 (gpio port 11 i think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mechanism to be notified when to wake up.  Perhaps gpio takes an option that will cause it to block until the desired event.  Otherwise, you'll just need to poll the device at regular intervals. Or, you can keep the spin loop and just not do any output. For example,

```
while sleep 1; do ...
```